# Multiple form and one modal

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

can you help me out with my problem?
I have multiple buttons and 1 modal. every time I clicked the button, the modal will show it up correctly. but I like to recode my modal. I like to echo the value of the button on the modal when I clicked the specific button.

for ex:

```
button 1. <value="button1"> ----> <a href="#myModal">
button 2. <value="button2"> ----> <a href="#myModal">
button 3. <value="button3"> ----> <a href="#myModal">
```

if I click the `button 2`, the `myModal` will show it up plus the value `button2` will show/echo it up on the `myModal`.

thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated. ^__^.

I forgot to mention: 
the modal is on a different body of HTML.

here is my Modal link and script code;

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn1").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

I don't know where could I put the given code to echo the button value?

Comment: use javascript / jquery to show your modal and change the html on modal .

Comment: have a title attribute on the button and then on the click you can get the title attribute value by $(this).attr('title')

Comment: thank you @Dhaval Chheda. I will try your given advice. ^__^

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be adding ids to buttons and then adding this in javascript function to open your modal

```
$(".modal-body #your_html").val($(this).data('id'));
```

Comment: thank you  @Abhilash Chaturvedi. I will try your given advice. ^__^

Comment: how could I echo the value of the button on the modal?

Comment: replace #your_html with #some_id and put in the modal where you want the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of current button.

```
$('.modal-body a').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: hello @shrikantbishoye thank you for the code. please see my edited post above. I don't know where could I put?

Comment: how could I echo the value of the button on the modal?